# Категоризация значений в нескольких столбцах DataFrame'а

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Дано: 700 столбцов с множеством похожих категориальных переменных object. 
Нужно: заменить названия этих переменных по всем наблюдениям так, чтобы было 4-5 значений. Делается это по фрагментам словосочетаний.

Код:

```
for n in df_court.columns:                                           # Для каждого столбца из датафрейма
    if df_court[n].dtype.name == 'object' and 'docName' in n:        # если тип переменной столбца object,и есть фрагмент docName
            for value in df_court[n]:                                # в названии, для каждого элемента столбца, если фрагмента
                if 'Исполнительный лист' in value:                   # "Исполнительный лист" есть в названии, то присовить 
                    value = 'Положительный фактор'                   # названию значени "положительный фактор"
                    print(value)                                     # проверка выводом на печать
```

Но он выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-cc61f6ae65fe> in <module>()
      2     if df_court[n].dtype.name == 'object' and 'docName' in n:
      3             for value in df_court[n]:
----> 4                 if 'Исполнительный' in value:
      5                     value = 'збс'
      6                     print(value)

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Подскажите корректный синтаксис, или логику, если в ней тоже ошибка.

Хотелось бы получить из входных данных:

```
Series:
nan   
Исполнительное производство
Исполнительное производство
Отзыв иска
Жалоба
Жалоба
Жалоба
Жалоба
Ходатайство
Иск удовлетворить
```

Подобный выход:

```
Series
Нейтральный фактор   # состоит из nan
Положительный фактор
Положительный фактор
Негативный фактор
Негативный фактор
Негативный фактор
Негативный фактор
Негативный фактор
Положительный фактор
Положительный фактор
```

То есть, переименовать категории по фрагментам словосочетаний, потому что все точные вариации словосочетаний спецтерминов не отследить

Comment: Уточнил запрос.

Comment: В приведённом примере - это значения одного столбца или наименования разных столбцов?

Comment: Да, это те самые values в столбце df_court[n], где n  - это имя столбца из df_court.columns

Comment: Теперь стало понятно. Напишу ответ когда доберусь до компьютера...

Comment: Вы просто джедай!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [35]: df
Out[35]:
                      docName1  num                     docName2
0                          nan   31                   Отзыв иска
1  Исполнительное производство    0                  Ходатайство
2  Исполнительное производство   29                       Жалоба
3                   Отзыв иска   43  Исполнительное производство
4                       Жалоба   34                          nan
5                       Жалоба   28            Иск удовлетворить
6                       Жалоба   93  Исполнительное производство
7                       Жалоба   62                       Жалоба
8                  Ходатайство   24                       Жалоба
9            Иск удовлетворить   82                       Жалоба
```

Решение: воспользуемся методом [DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
positive = ['исполнительн.*\sпроизводств.*','ходатайство','иск\s*удовлетворить']
negative = ['отзыв\s*иска','жалоб.*']
neutral = ['nan']

def categorize(df, positive=positive, negative=negative, neutral=neutral):
    neg = '^{}$'.format('|'.join(negative))
    pos = '^{}$'.format('|'.join(positive))
    neut = '^{}$'.format('|'.join(neutral))
    return df.replace([neg, pos, neut],
                      ['Положительный фактор','Негативный фактор',
                       'Нейтральный фактор'],
                      regex=True)

mask = df.columns.str.contains('docName\d+') & df.dtypes.eq('object')
df.loc[:, mask] = categorize(df.loc[:, mask].apply(lambda x: x.str.lower()),
                             positive=positive,
                             negative=negative,
                             neutral=neutral)
```

Результат:

```
In [41]: df
Out[41]:
               docName1  num              docName2
0    Нейтральный фактор   31  Положительный фактор
1     Негативный фактор    0     Негативный фактор
2     Негативный фактор   29  Положительный фактор
3  Положительный фактор   43     Негативный фактор
4  Положительный фактор   34    Нейтральный фактор
5  Положительный фактор   28     Негативный фактор
6  Положительный фактор   93     Негативный фактор
7  Положительный фактор   62  Положительный фактор
8     Негативный фактор   24  Положительный фактор
9     Негативный фактор   82  Положительный фактор
```

Comment: Почему-то не работает...Столбцы остаются неизменные

Comment: @StepanSokol, даже не знаю как вам помочь не имея __воспроизводимого__ набора данных...

Comment: А если ли способ решить эту задачу без регулярок? Она по идее сводится к корректной адресации по строкам определенного столбца.

Comment: @StepanSokol, конечно, замените регулярки строковыми литералами и уберите параметр `regex=True`. Просто в этом случае сравнивается значение ячейки целиком - замена/поиск подстрок так работать не будет. Поэтому, для гибкости, я использовал регулярки...

Comment: @StepanSokol, мне кажется было бы проще если бы вы смогли создать не очень большой, но максимально похожий на ваши данные, набор данных и выложить его в виде CSV или Excel файла на каком-нибудь файлообменнике и привести результирующий / желаемый набор данных. Тогда бы вы смогли воспольщоваться решением, не переделывая/адаптируя его... PS в этом случае стоит открыть новый вопрос